# Literature on the Kakeya needle problem for convex sets

Tags: geometry, reference-request

I'm reading about the Kakeya needle problem. There is the result that the smallest area for a convex set where you can fully turn a needle is the area of an equilateral triangle with height 1.

This was proved in 1928 by Pal and I am looking for a newer version of the proof (it does not matter if it is in a paper, lecture notes or in a book). However so far I only managed to find the original.

Does anyone know where to find extra material on this?

Answer (score 2):

You might try this American Mathematical Monthly article: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2317619?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents 
-- that link will even let you read it for free if you don't mind signing up for an account.  It has a reasonable amount of detail and develops the problem additionally for star-shaped sets.  The list of references is quite short though, suggesting that it might be hard to find a lot of literature on the problem.

F. Cunningham Jr. did write another article on the Kakeya problem three years later (The American Mathematical Monthly Volume 81, 1974 - Issue 6) but the references there go no further.

Comment: Vincent Borrelli and Jean-Luc Rullière (Ecole Normale Supérieure de Lyon) have written a very nice book on the subject (in French) "En cheminant avec Kakeya" in 2014 that you will find online there : http://catalogue-editions.ens-lyon.fr/html/WYSIWYGfiles/files/349_Borrelli_pdf%20WEB.pdf. Here is a slideshow produced out of their book : http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~borrelli/UO/essentiel_conf4.pdf